# Transitioning git repos to submodules inside git-annex?

Tags: git, version-control, git-annex

For a while I've been using Dropbox with ~/Documents symlinked inside, which includes several git repos, so I have been indulging in the frowned-upon practice of synchronising the same git repos across machines, instead of push/pulling. I'd like to transition from Dropbox to git-annex, but I realise that this would mean nesting my existing git repos inside the super-repo of ~/Documents.

My question is, how do I do this with git-annex, such that the ~/Documents folder will synchronise across machines, while retaining all branches, etc. of the repos contained therein? Should my children repos be converted into submodules of the ~/Documents repo?

I'm pretty sure I won't be branching the ~/Documents git-annex repo, but I will be continuing development on various branches in the repos inside.

I've been reading the git-annex docs, but there doesn't seem to be clear consensus on git repos inside git-annex repos.

Nb. I'm already running git-annex in direct mode.